# Chrome Extension to debug and edit code in the browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, remote-debugging, read-eval-print-loop

I am building a web based JS REPL (similar to http://jsfiddle.net/), but I find it really annoying to have to switch between the Chrome Developer Console and my own code to debug. I have a text area on the left (using the wonderful [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)) and clicking a preview button loads another window into an iframe on the right with the code I was editing. It made me wonder, what if I was able to add breakpoints to my code editor in the browser window and when it hits the breakpoint I could see the state of variables, step through the code, and remove breakpoints all while still editing the code in the editor. Very similar to real debugging, but in the browser instead of an editor like Eclipse.

I think a Chrome Extension is the right way to go. I can make calls to the debugger using [the debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html), then add breakpoints, step over, step out, etc. using [this protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/debugger). This works great and I can even get the current state of variables when the breakpoint is hit using [Runtime.getProperties](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/runtime#command-getProperties).

**The problem is...** that once I pause the code to debug, everything on the entire page freezes (of course, because I'm debugging). Can anyone think of a way to get around this? The ideal solution would allow me to freeze and debug the result on the right in the iframe and still manipulate the code on the left.